# Oracle Schema Doubt?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, postgresql, migration

Currently am using postgres with diff schemas for diff modules.Now i am planning to switch towards oracle.But i heard that in oracle schema is not there..Is it true..if it is like that how can i migrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, each user has his own schema. You can select across them if permissions are granted.